# Setting AppDelegate Shared instance to nil does not create warning or crash

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate

In my app, i have done something like this,

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 //some code
 appDelegate = nil;
```

But, App runs fine and does not give warning or crash.

Can anybody explain this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you made `appDelegate` point to `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`. Then you made it point to nowhere. But `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` remains the same. You did nothing with it. You didn't even touch it.

What you probably are thinking of is:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setDelegate:nil];
```

But it also shouldn't produce warnings or crashes. It should only result in not calling app delegate methods since messages sent to nil do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

[`[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` will give you a pointer to your app delegate,the one that was automatically created when you made the project. So setting appDelegate = nil, just sets the pointer to the app delegate to nil. Does not do anything to app delegate, the one that is automatically created..

Answer (score 1):

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Using this line it return you a shared instance of appDelegate.

`[UIApplication sharedApplication]` --- gives access to the singleton

`delegate` method returns a pointer to the app delegate.
and when you assign nil to appDelegate after finishing all works. Why will it crash?
Pobably if you will try to call a method after assigning it nil value. That will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your `appDelegate` pointer to `nil` not the delegate of the app. After you write this code, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` would still not be `nil`.